# Which microphone is used during FaceTime video call in iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, facetime, microphone

I have an issue with my iPhone SE running iOS 11.4.1. I already spoke with support, and they are saying that it is hardware issue.

Do you know which microphone it is used during video conversation in FaceTime? Because this microphone works pretty well, but when I record something in Camera app, I hear only noise. Whatsapp, Messenger, Siri can't hear me too.

I already did a fresh install of iOS using iTunes. If this is hardware issue, then microphone shouldn't also work during videocall on FaceTime, or FaceTime is using other (bottom) microphone. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 microphones in the iPhone.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203792

- The bottom microphone is for Voice Memo and phone calls. The other microphones serve as error cancellation
- The (top) front microphone is used for FaceTime calls, Siri and selfie videos with the front camera (FCAM). The top back microphone serves as error cancellation
- The (top) back microphone is used for videos with the rear camera (RCAM). The top front microphone serves as error cancellation

Make sure you update your device to the latest version of iOS and then try to isolate which microphone is not working properly by trying each individual microphone with the related apps above. If the issue affects more than one microphone, then it could be the Audio Codec IC on the logic board.

Answer (score 1):

After doing much research as I have similar problem on my daughters phone, it seems apps like WhatsApp when on speakerphone use the front top microphone where as FaceTime on speakerphone uses front bottom microphone. Easy check is to record a front face video and hear of sound is captured.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, and it seems that FaceTime is using bottom mic, not front - it is a mistake in this article. 
Phone calls, voice memo works
Camera, siri does not work.
FaceTime video conf works.

Answer (score 0):

You should take your phone to Apple Support. They will replace the **front microphone**. That is the microphone used for Siri and Facetime.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7076466)

> That would be the front microphone. You would need to have the phone checked at an Apple Store. If you try to do any repairs yourself, you will void any future support from Apple.